# Armstrong circuit board

Tags: heating

What would cause the burn spot around the white diode? on the left side of circuit board st9160b 1068 I notice it on all the pictures I have seen

Comment: What burn spot? What photographs? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Is this a general question or do you have the Armstrong (unit of some sort) yourself and have this burn spot? Is the unit still functioning or has this disabled the unit? Is `ST9160B 1068` a model number for the Armstrong unit or just the board itself? Please give us some details in the hopes that we can answer your question...

Answer (score 1):

Diodes burn due to overload conditions where too much current flows through them.  Generally that is a symptom of another problem, not a problem in and of itself.  Although if burned sufficiently enough the diode will not function as intended and this may adversely affect the overall circuit operation.